# Power BI - Show all data from table1 in a visual from two many to many related tables when one other field from table2 on the X-axis

Tags: database, powerbi, many-to-many, dax

I have a key column in two many  to many related table and sample representation of data is -

(attaching sample version of the table to get the point across as there are other numerous columns not contributing to this visual)

table 1 -

[image: table 1]

table 2 -

[image: table 2]

I am making a line graph with date on x axis and the value1 and value 2 on y-axis. The value1 is true for  all dates. It is basically a standard target value. Now I want all the value1 summed up to show in my visual as value1 and  not just the ones for which I have data on those dates. To explain it better I want 1717 on the graph as well like the total in the table in the following image -

visual -

[image: table 3]

Is there a way to do this in power BI? I tried to make a shared dimension of all unique key as a separate table and connecting both the tables to that table but there is no change in visual due to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these below steps to achieve your required output-

**Step-1** Create a **custom column** in your **table 1* as below-

```
value_1_sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(table_2[value1]),
    ALL(table_2)
)
```

**Step-2** Configure your line chart as below. Remember, the aggregation for new custom column will be **Average** as shown in the image

[image]

And here below is the final output-

[image]

**Additional Reference** Here below is list of options you will get after right click on the measure name-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I've asked this question in a lot of forums and you are the only one who has got the chart I needed. 

Excuse my newb-ness, but how do you aggregate this measure as average. When I right click, I don't find any such option which I do in other table columns such as value1 and value2. Also why is the average aggregation needed?

Comment: Aggregation is required as there are same value repeated in each row. So average will keep the same value :) I will show the average option soon in my updated answe soon.